# Sizing a Transformer

Tags: transformer

I'm trying to spec out a 3-Phase transformer for a project i'm working on, I know that the max load is going to be 40.3kW & I know that the total FLA is 82 Amps operating at 480V @ 60hz, but I do not have the RMS draw or power Factor. I was thinking about using a 45KVA transformer, but would this be too small of a transformer?

I read somewhere online that Transformers perform their best at 3/4 of their maximum load. Is this claim true? Would I need to spec a transformer out so that my 40.3kW load is 75% of the Transformer's maximum KVA rating?

Comment: 40 kW is a large project to be asking random strangers on the internet how to design it. First, the load, what is its RMS draw? Power factor? Those may not be obvious if it's a rectifier. Second, your environment, temperature? Opportunities for cooling - free convection, forced air, liquid - will all affect the rating of the transformer. Duty cycle? Long term reliability? You have a lot of specification work to do before you even ask a transformer manufacturer to quote to you. Or if you have the budget, just go for a big over-rating, load = 75% of max rating is maybe enough, and hope.

Comment: Neil, Thanks for the reply. The load that i've been given is a value I've calculated from a Vendor's quote where I've only been giving the total FLA and operating voltage (82 Amps and 480V @ 60hz ) The transformer is expected to be operating in just ambient air conditions. Since I don't have the RMS draw or Power Factor, if I decide to shoot for a big over-rating, let says a 55KVA Transformer, the load would ideally be 73% of the total KVA rating. Would this be a big enough safety net or should I look towards something as big as a 60KVA transformer?

Comment: You should add this info to your question.

Comment: Ambient = 72degF/22C controlled +/-3, or up to 140F/60C?  I've seen 140 in a vented panel when ambient was 96; any xfmr will eventually fail this hot unless an exotic insulation class.  There are too many unknowns here; if it were mine, I'd hire a licensed electrician to consult, inspect, and give a recommendation.  That way if it blows up in 2 years, it's at least partly their fault and not all yours.  P.S. ensure all connections are *very* clean (400-grit sandpaper) and *very* tight (use lockwashers); seen lots of catastrophic failures from dirty/loose connections lately.

Comment: The problem with a transformer **rated** for some load is that's specified under **rated conditions**. If your environment doesn't match those conditions, the rating is meaningless. Load waveform is likely to be one difference, temperature and cooling conditions another. Sag in voltage between no load and rated load? Expected lifetime of insulation at temperature?

Comment: Consider having your electrical installer make a recommendation, that way you get a guarantee it they install it.